# AIR Native Extension issue

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, ane

I built an AIR native extension with following setup:

1. Visual studio 2005 for building my dll
2. Flash CS6 IDE with AIR SDK 3.2 to create SWC from my AS3 source
3. The namespace version of my ANE is 33.1
4. ADT (AIR SDK 33.1)

I tested the ANE with FlashDevelop 5.3.3.1 and the ANE works as expected on a machine that I use for development. However, when I test the same ANE in FlashDevelop on a different machine, the AIR can't find a necessary method in the native side implementation (Error code #3500). I am using the same version of FlashDevelop with same AIR SDK (33.1) in both machines.
It seems that for some reason AIR could not load the dll in second machine (but does so in my development machine), and I am not sure why. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing some of the dependency dlls, most likely part of the vc++ redistributable package or potentially .net if you are using any of that functionality.

Try to install the VC++ redist on your test machine:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0